# Can I use more than 1 Selenium browser instance with PHP?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I read that the Selenium driver might limit the amount of browser instances you can have open at a time. It is my intention to use a PHP & MySQL queuing system to watch a MySQL table for tasks it needs to perform in Selenium and for each task it spawns a PHP script which executes the web automation task using the Selenium driver. Will I be able to spawn as many instances of the script I want for lets say Chromium? BTW I'm planning to run this all on Linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. What you need is Selenium Grid.

And the good news is that Selenium Grid is much more easy and robust on the Linux machines. You can configure, the number of browsers you need and other stuffs for the grid.

In theory you can set up to any number of browsers, that will run in parallel. But you should be limiting the numbers according to the system's hardware and the need.

Look at [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp)